# Which HBase connector for Spark 2.0 should I use?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-bigtable

Our stack is composed of Google Data Proc (Spark 2.0) and Google BigTable (HBase 1.2.0) and I am looking for a connector working with these versions.

The Spark 2.0 and the new DataSet API support is not clear to me for the connectors I have found:

- **spark-hbase** : https://github.com/apache/hbase/tree/master/hbase-spark
- **spark-hbase-connector** : https://github.com/nerdammer/spark-hbase-connector
- **hortonworks-spark/shc** : https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc

The project is written in Scala 2.11 with SBT.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update**: SHC now seems to work with Spark 2 and the Table API. See https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-bigtable-examples/tree/master/scala/bigtable-shc

**Original answer:**

I don't believe any of these (or any other existing connector) will do all that you would like today.

- **spark-hbase** will probably the right solution when it is release (HBase 1.4?), but currently only builds at head and [is still working on Spark 2 support](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-16179).
- **spark-hbase-connector** only seems to support RDD APIs, but since they are more stable, might be somewhat helpful.
- **hortonworks-spark/shc** probably won't work because I believe it only supports Spark 1 and uses the older HTable APIs which do not work with BigTable.

I would recommend just using HBase MapReduce APIs with RDD methods like newAPIHadoopRDD (or possibly the spark-hbase-connector?). Then manually convert RDDs into DataSets. This approach is a lot easier in Scala or Java than Python.

This is an area that the HBase community is working to improve and Google Cloud Dataproc will incorporate those improvements as they happen.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this what I have done for read and it works quite well with `spark.sparkContext.newAPIHadoopRDD(config, classOf[TableInputFormat],classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable],classOf[Result])`. How should I use this API for bulk writes ?

Comment: Simply with saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(...)

Comment: Looks like hortonworks released a version for Spark 2: https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc/tree/v1.0.1-2.0

Comment: Does spark-hbase compatible with Scala 2.11 ? I think it is built for Scala 2.10 https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/hbase/hbase-spark/2.0.0-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: any update on this again? I want to sort hbase (non-rowkey) column to get rowkeys corresponding to top ten column values. Will doing this in spark using spark-hbase connector run fast?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the above answer, using `newAPIHadoopRDD` means that, you get all the data from HBase and from then on, its all core spark. You would not get any HBase specific API like Filters etc.
And the current spark-hbase, only snapshots are available.