# how to visit hbase using spark 2.*

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase

I have wrote a program which visit HBase using spark 1.6 with spark-hbase-connecotr ( sbt dependency: "it.nerdammer.bigdata" % "spark-hbase-connector_2.10" % "1.0.3"). But it doesn't work when using spark 2.*. I've searched about this question and I got some concludes:

1. there are several connectors used to connect hbase using spark

   - hbase-spark. hbase-spark is provided by HBase official [website](https://github.com/apache/hbase/tree/master/hbase-spark). But I found it is developed on scala 2.10 and spark 1.6. The properties in the pom.xml of the project is as below:

     ```
     <properties>
       <spark.version>1.6.0</spark.version>
       <scala.version>2.10.4</scala.version>
       <scala.binary.version>2.10</scala.binary.version>
       <top.dir>${project.basedir}/..</top.dir>
       <avro.version>1.7.6</avro.version>
       <avro.mapred.classifier></avro.mapred.classifier>
     </properties>
     ```
   - hbase-spark-connecotr: I visit their [website](https://github.com/nerdammer/spark-hbase-connector/blob/master/README.md) and there is no information about spark 2.0. And the jar's name is spark-hbase-connector_2.10 that tell us the jar is compiled by scala 2.10 used by spark 1.* . But when I change the jar's name to spark-hbase-connector_2.11(compiled by scala 2.11,the same as spark 2.),my IEDA(a kind of IDE) tell me no jar named spark-hbase-connecotr_2.11.So there is no support for spark 2. .
   - hortonworks-spark: I 've visited their website. Some remarks said that is is not support for spark 2.*.

Do you know any jar provided by third party with full document which solve the problem? what packages should I use to connect the hbase using spark 2.* ? I appreciate you for any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which HBase connector for Spark 2.0 should I use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40908891/which-hbase-connector-for-spark-2-0-should-i-use)

Comment: See below links
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51566176/how-to-access-hbase-from-spark-scala-is-there-clear-defined-scala-api https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40908891/which-hbase-connector-for-spark-2-0-should-i-use?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I choose using [newAPIHadoopRDD](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD) to visit hbase in spark

Comment: Using this will perform a full Scan operation though.  Is there any way to perform a get by rowkey using Spark 2?