# How to access HBase from Spark.scala? is there clear defined scala api?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase

How to access HBase from Spark.scala? is there any clear defined scala api? I am looking at dataframe level instead of RDD's.

Many options available over web like
Apache HBase Connector
SparkOnHBase
 and more options there.

But it would be nice to know or use most used in the industry.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark-Hbase connector by Hortonworks is widely used to access HBase from Spark.
It provides an API in both low-level RDD and Dataframes.

The connector requires you to define a Schema for HBase table. Below is an example of Schema defined for a HBase table with name as table1, row key as key and a number of columns (col1-col8). Note that the rowkey also has to be defined in details as a column (col0), which has a specific cf (rowkey).

```
def catalog = s"""{
        |"table":{"namespace":"default", "name":"table1"},
        |"rowkey":"key",
        |"columns":{
          |"col0":{"cf":"rowkey", "col":"key", "type":"string"},
          |"col1":{"cf":"cf1", "col":"col1", "type":"boolean"},
          |"col2":{"cf":"cf2", "col":"col2", "type":"double"},
          |"col3":{"cf":"cf3", "col":"col3", "type":"float"},
          |"col4":{"cf":"cf4", "col":"col4", "type":"int"},
          |"col5":{"cf":"cf5", "col":"col5", "type":"bigint"},
          |"col6":{"cf":"cf6", "col":"col6", "type":"smallint"},
          |"col7":{"cf":"cf7", "col":"col7", "type":"string"},
          |"col8":{"cf":"cf8", "col":"col8", "type":"tinyint"}
        |}
      |}""".stripMargin
```

To Read HBase table as a Dataframe:

```
val df = spark
  .read
  .options(Map(HBaseTableCatalog.tableCatalog->cat))
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase")
  .load()
```

To write Dataframe to HBase table:

```
df.write.options(
  Map(HBaseTableCatalog.tableCatalog -> catalog, HBaseTableCatalog.newTable -> "5"))
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase")
  .save()
```

For more details: https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc

Comment: Thanks for the reply. +1

Comment: Is there a way to generate catalog string automatically based on HBase table?

Comment: Unfortunately, no! We have to manually define the schema based on table.