# Spark Structured Streaming Kafka Avro to Hbase

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, hbase, avro, spark-structured-streaming

As described in [Spark Structured Streaming with Hbase integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152015/spark-structured-streaming-with-hbase-integration), I'm interesting in writing data to HBase in structured streaming framework. I've cloned SHC code from github, extend it by sync provider and trying to write records to HBase. Buy, I've received error: """Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start(). My python code is below:

**JARS**

**Spark verdion: 2.4.0, scala.version: 2.11.8, com.hortonworks.shc-core: 1.1.1-2.1-s_2.11 spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11**

```
    spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("SparkConsumer") \
        .getOrCreate()

    print 'read Avro schema from file: {}...'.format(schema_name)
    schema = avro.schema.parse(open(schema_name, 'rb').read())
    reader = avro.io.DatumReader(schema)
    print 'the schema is read'

    rows = spark \
        .readStream \
        .format('kafka') \
        .option('kafka.bootstrap.servers', brokers) \
        .option('subscribe', topic) \
        .option('group.id', group_id) \
        .option('maxOffsetsPerTrigger', 1000) \
        .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
        .load()
    rows.printSchema()

    schema = StructType([ \
            StructField('consumer_id', StringType(), False), \
            StructField('audit_system_id', StringType(), False), \
            StructField('object_path', StringType(), True), \
            StructField('object_type', StringType(), False), \
            StructField('what_action', StringType(), False), \
            StructField('when', LongType(), False), \
            StructField('where', StringType(), False), \
            StructField('who', StringType(), True), \
            StructField('workstation', StringType(), True) \
        ])

    def decode_avro(msg):
        bytes_reader = io.BytesIO(bytes(msg))
        decoder = avro.io.BinaryDecoder(bytes_reader)
        data = reader.read(decoder)
        return (\
                data['consumer_id'],\
                data['audit_system_id'],\
                data['object_path'],\
                data['object_type'],\
                data['what_action'],\
                data['when'],\
                data['where'],\
                data['who'],\
                data['workstation']\
               )

    udf_decode_avro = udf(decode_avro, schema)

    values = rows.select('value')
    values.printSchema()

    changes = values.withColumn('change', udf_decode_avro(col('value'))).select('change.*')
    changes.printSchema()

    change_catalog = '''
    {
        "table":
        {
            "namespace": "uba_input",
            "name": "changes"
        },
        "rowkey": "consumer_id",
        "columns":
        {
            "consumer_id": {"cf": "rowkey", "col": "consumer_id", "type": "string"},
            "audit_system_id": {"cf": "data", "col": "audit_system_id", "type": "string"},
            "object_path": {"cf": "data", "col": "object_path", "type": "string"},
            "object_type": {"cf": "data", "col": "object_type", "type": "string"},
            "what_action": {"cf": "data", "col": "what_action", "type": "string"},
            "when": {"cf": "data", "col": "when", "type": "bigint"},
            "where": {"cf": "data", "col": "where", "type": "string"},
            "who": {"cf": "data", "col": "who", "type": "string"},
            "workstation": {"cf": "data", "col": "workstation", "type": "string"}
        }
    }'''

    query = changes \
        .writeStream \
        .outputMode("append") \
        .format('HBase.HBaseSinkProvider')\
        .option('hbasecat', change_catalog) \
        .option("checkpointLocation", '/tmp/checkpoint') \
        .start()

#        .format('org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase')\
#    query = changes \
#        .writeStream \
#        .format('console') \
#        .start()

    query.awaitTermination()
```