# Spark2 On HBase Cloudera

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hbase, cloudera, apache-spark-2.0

I am getting the exception below while trying to connect **HBase** from **spark2** and insert some data using the **HBaseConfiguration**.

```
18/03/05 15:18:47 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hbase/HBaseConfiguration
```

I read on **Cloudera** that **Spark2** On **HBase** is not Supported as Spark On HBase is a CDH component that has a dependency on Spark 1.6. Is there any workaround to insert data into **HBase** from **Spark2**?

Comment: You're just missing a dependency... Not exactly a problem with Spark 2. How are you running the code? Are you adding any external packages?

Comment: I am running the code on the Yarn cluster. I added this configuration (--conf spark.driver.extraClassPath="/etc/hbase/conf"   --conf spark.yarn.security.tokens.hbase.enabled=false) in the spark properties. Also, writing to Hbase was working fine on Spark 1.6.

Comment: Okay, well according to here, there is no such available connector for Spark2 yet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40908891/which-hbase-connector-for-spark-2-0-should-i-use